# MSX Assembly/Basic programming documentation

Tags: programming, assembly, basic, msx

I'd like to try to create software (and maybe simple games) for the MSX standard.

I know I have two ways to do so, either I use MSX Basic or Z80 assembly. I think that Z80 assembly is more powerful than MSX Basic.

I already have experience with programming but I never did on old systems like the MSX.

I'd like to know if anyone has good ressources/tutorials/guides on how to develop programs for the MSX strandard.

I'd also like to know if there are any ways to develop such programs on a modern day system (maybe via emulator). I'm currently running Linux Mint, is there any kind of "IDE" that would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 17):

Here are some useful resources for MSX development (**disclaimer**: all created by me)

- [MSX2 Technical Handbook:](https://github.com/Konamiman/msx2-Technical-Handbook) A must to learn how the internals of MSX computers work, and also a reference of MSX BIOS and MSX BASIC commands. *Originally published by ASCII Corporation in paper, I converted it to text files back in the 90s and then to a GitHub repository in 2019).*
- If you want to develop using C, a very good tool is [SDCC](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/). If you want to give it a try, take a look at [the libraries I have developed](http://www.konamiman.com/msx/msx-e.html#sdcc).
- If you prefer assembly, take a look at [Sjasm](https://github.com/Konamiman/Sjasm), a very nice assembler. *Originally developed by Sjoerd Mastijn and distributed as a ZIP file, I published it as a Git repository and added compatibility with the MSX assembler Compass.*
- [My MSX software repository](https://github.com/Konamiman/MSX) can be useful if you like to learn by reading others' source code.

But enough of me! Other fine resources by other amazing MSX users are:

- [The Wiki on the MSX Resource Center](https://www.msx.org/wiki/)
- [MSX Info Pages](http://msx.hansotten.com/) by Hans Otten, especially [the Technical Info section](http://msx.hansotten.com/index.php?page=msxhw)
- [MSX Assembly Page](http://map.grauw.nl/) by Grauw has a ton of useful information

(Side note: if you need to learn (or refresh) Z80, did you know that Programming the Z80 by Rodnay Zaks [is available online?](http://www.z80.info/zaks.html))

As for the IDE, I just use Visual Studio (since I use it for work anyway) as a simple text editor and build by running SDCC or Sjasm from the command line. Other people use different tools, adapting them to their needs; here is for example [an article on how to use Eclipse to develop for SDCC](http://andrear.altervista.org/home/sdcceclipse.php). But I don't know of any IDE specifically built for MSX (or any other retro platform) development.

Comment: Nice! What do you use to create the MSX binary file header, please? It's the only part of my answer that relies on the rather large z88dk package, and it's a trivial task

Comment: The header for BLOADable files? I just put this at the beginning of the file: `db 0FEh - dw startAddress - dw endAddress - dw runAddress`

Answer (score 7):

I've found that the [MSX Assembly Page](http://map.grauw.nl/) has some great resources.  I think their [Z80 instruction set overview](http://map.grauw.nl/resources/z80instr.php) page and [code samples](http://map.grauw.nl/sources/) are just what you're looking for.

The [noob guide](https://www.msx.org/forum/development/msx-development/vampiers-quest-assembly-hopefully-n00b-guide-assembly) on MSX.org may also help you.

(I realize that this is pretty much a link-only answer.  If I can, I will try to elaborate on this answer and provide additional resources.)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I've just installed `openmsx` and a few compilers to try to set up a working devlopment environment. I currently have a problem where none of my Z80 assembly compilers seem to want to compile a simple "Hello world" I found to test them. I tried `asmsx`, `pasmo` and `z80asm` (all of them on Linux). Is there any sample MSX Z80 assembly code I could try to compile to test those compilers? I need to have a stable environment before I go deeper in learning assembly.

Comment: What Hello World example are you using?  [This one?](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Z80_Assembly/Hello_World)

Comment: I tried this one, and the three compilers failed (`asmsx`, `z80asm` and `pasmo`).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a small *Hello, World!* in Z80 Assembly, built entirely through cross-assembly and emulation:

```
    ;; hello-msx.asm - hello world for msx - scruss
    org 40000
CHPUT:  equ $00A2

    ld hl, msg
    call puts
    ret
    
puts:               ; print 0-terminated string in HL
    ld a,(hl)
    or a
    ret z
    call CHPUT      ; displays one character in A
    inc hl
    jr puts
    
msg:    defm "Hello, world!",13,10,0
```

Compile it to a simple binary image with [z80asm](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/z80asm):

```
z80asm -o hello-msx.bin hello-msx.asm
```

Convert this to an MSX binary with header using [z88dk](https://www.z88dk.org/wiki/doku.php)'s appmake command:

```
appmake +msx -b hello-msx.bin -o hellomsx.msx
```

This MSX binary can be copied to a disk image. MSX disks were 720 KB DSDD FAT images, so there are lots of ways of making these. I used [MSX Disk Image](https://sites.google.com/site/slumpmax/development/msx-home-computer/msxdiskimage), mainly because remembering all the right commands for dd, mkfs and mount are too much for me to remember.

With openmsx and suitable ROMs, you can run it from disk:

```
openmsx -machine msx2 -diska msx1.dsk
```

[image: openmsx showing output]

Notes:

1. z80asm is supposed to include some MSX-specific library files. As I only used one [BIOS call](http://map.grauw.nl/resources/msxbios.php), including them was a bit much.
2. z88dk *also* has an assembler called z80asm, and it's not compatible with the one I used. z88dk has some MSX specific options: [MSX hints & tools](https://www.z88dk.org/wiki/doku.php?id=platform:msx) — though if you're using a packaged Linux distribution, it may not support all of the newer options.
3. Although shown running on an MSX2, this code is MSX 1 compatible. I only used MSX2 as it has obvious disk suport, and my version of z88dk didn't seem to support audio for making cassette images.
4. z88dk can also develop from a Small C dialect, creating MSX binaries directly: `zcc +msx -create-app -o hello-c hello.c`

Comment: Nowadays, MSX Pen makes it far easier to test simple programs in Assembly or Basic for MSX.

Comment: @AndréBaptista — MSX Pen looks neat! Undelete your answer, please, because it really adds to this question

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, [MSX Pen](https://msxpen.com/) makes it far easier to test simple programs in Assembly or Basic for MSX.

Comment: Also, 8 Bit workshop has a complete online IDE for MSX Development, in C and Asm, beside many other computers and consoles. Highly recommended.

Comment: Yes, [8bitworkshop IDE \[msx\]](https://8bitworkshop.com/v3.10.0/?platform=msx&file=helloworld.asm) is very neat too